# Create object objective c

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

So say I created a class SoapService like so:

```
@implementation _SoapService
{
}

- (int)doStuff
{
    return 5;
}

@end
```

how would I create an instance of SoapService in another class to use the doStuff method (I realize the method doesn't really do much)

if that didn't make sense I want to do something like this if it were c#:

```
SoapService soap = new SoapService();

int i = soap.doStuff();
```

I'm having trouble finding any good beginner tutorials that are not just hello world.

Comment: Is there any tag for such question? It is about basic stuff anyone can find in docs about Objective-C.

Comment: You can use c++ in XCode with no need for Objective C objects until you do the user interface

Comment: @Aleksejs Thanks for the helpful input. I apologize for not finding what I needed, that's why I was asking here. Like I said I am having trouble finding good beginner resources. You may not find my question constructive, but it is equally not constructive to leave comments like yours. How about giving a helpful link instead of just calling it a dumb question and down voting off the whip. Have a good one buddy.

Comment: @Nick I really believe that basic information about any programming language you're interested in you find easily. If you are new in Objective-C, I suggest you to check Stanford lectures at iTunes U: http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=395605774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SoapService *soap = [[SoapService alloc] init];
int i = [soap doStuff];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SoapService *soap = [[SoapService alloc] init];

int i = [soap doStuff];
```